# Can't find certain Boost library function

Tags: c#, c++, boost, tree, nearest-neighbor

I am trying to implement a k-d tree in C# and the source I'm looking at is in C++ with Boost. The function I'm trying to find is `util::subtract()`. I've searched all through Boost's documentation and I can't find it anywhere.

Line number 94 is the function I'm trying to translate.
The full file can be found here: https://github.com/gvd/kdtree/blob/master/kdtree.h

If someone has a better source that I can implement from, I'd greatly appreciate that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking at is a C++ inlined function template and it is actually defined at the top of the header file you linked (thus the `util::` namespace rather than `boost::` namespace). In C#, it looks like you could implement this logic in a static function if you lift the `Dimension` field out of the C++ enclosing `struct` and pass it simply as a 4th argument to the C# static function.

There are 3 different function template definitions for `subtract(...)`, but only one with substance. I'll include that function template body here for completeness (note that it contains a recursive call where the `Dimension` field is used as a counter that will limit the recursion as soon as it equals `dim`):

```
   template <typename Point, std::size_t Dimension, std::size_t Count>
   struct dimension_extractor {
       static inline typename boost::geometry::default_distance_result<Point>::type subtract(const Point &p1, const Point &p2, std::size_t dim) {
            if (Dimension == dim) {
                return boost::geometry::get<Dimension>(p1) - boost::geometry::get<Dimension>(p2);
            }
            return dimension_extractor<Point, Dimension + 1, Count>::subtract(p1, p2, dim);
       }
   };
```

Admittedly without examining the `boost::geometry` libraries, a direct cursory port to C# might look something like this pseudo-code:

```
public static boost.geometry.default_distance_result<Point>.type subtract(Point p1, Point p2, uint dim, uint currDim)
{
    if (currDim == dim)
    {
        // it looks like .get() is a templated function, so the actual call syntax may be somewhat different
        return boost.geometry.get(p1, currDim) - boost.geometry.get(p2, currDim);
    }
    else
        return subtract(p1, p2, dim, currDim + 1);
}
```

In the C++ context, it seems like the `currDim` argument (representing the `Dimension` struct field) is always initialized at zero and incremented until it reaches `dim`. I'm not sure why this apparently unnecessary recursion is taking place--it might just be a C++ compiler trick (the C++ templates are often a bit less clear than the related C# generics). If this is the case, you might just be able to remove the recursion aspect from the C# code completely.

Comment: So what exactly is this function doing? I can't seem to follow it.

Comment: Updated the answer. The recursion is probably not necessary. The required arguments for the `boost.geometry.get( )` function will likely make the proper implementation clear.

Comment: So basically what it's doing is getting a point at a certain dimension, then subtracting from the other point?

Comment: Yes. If you have 2 N-dimensional points `p1` and `p2`, it looks like it is simply grabbing the value at a specified dimension on `p1` and subtracting the value at the same dimension in `p2`. Depending on whether the dimensions are represented in array format or categorical (property) format you could consider it either `(p1[dim] - p2[dim])` or `(p1.dim - p2.dim)`.